# VMExtensionProvisioningError while deploying a virtual machine

Tags: c#, .net, json, azure

I am trying to deploy a virtual machine in azure via JSON using as much as possible JSON templates and parameters, when i try to generate an extension for the VM i get the error:

"VMExtensionProvisioningError"

with the message:

"Failed to decode, decrypt, and deserialize the protected settings string. Error Message: Keyset does not exist"

And i dont know what this stands for.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
  ],
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'/CustomScriptExtension')]",
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.7",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion" :  true,
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": [
        "https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/{scriptName}"
      ],
      "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "{scriptName}" ')]"
    },
    "protectedSettings": { "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]" }
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions"
},
```

What i am trying is to execute a script obtained from a blob in Azure.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Not really a workaround since you clearly want (and should) use protected settings for storing sensitive data, but can you try removing the "protectedSettings" part entirely? Assuming you have the storageAccountName defined as a parameter. Just to see if it is the reason for causing the error. Generally keyset errors seem to be related to cryptography, and my personal ARM knowledge is limited on how is it applied in this case.

Comment: You need to add "storageAccountKey" for the "storageAccountName" in "protectedSettings".